# passing a substring to a function

Tags: c++, parsing, lisp

I am working on building the LISP interpreter. The problem I am stuck at is where I need to send the entire substring to a function as soon as I encounter a "(".
For example, if I have,

```
( begin  ( set x  2 ) (set y 3 ) )
```

then I need to pass

```
begin  ( set x  2 ) (set y 3 ) )
```

and when I encounter "(" again
 I need to pass

```
set x  2 ) (set y 3 ) )
```

then

```
set y 3 ) )
```

I tried doing so with substr by calculating length, but that didn't quite work. If anyone could help, that'd be great.

Requested code

```
int a=0;
listnode *makelist(string t) //t is the substring 
{
     //some code
     istringstream iss(t); 
     string word;
     while(iss>>word){
         if(word=="(")//I used strcmp here. Just for the sake for time saving I wrote this
         //some operations
             int x=word.size();
     a=a+x;
     word=word.substr(a);
     p->down=makelist(word);//function called again and word here should be the substring
}}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Usually with these things, it's a small problem... [When I did this, I used C, and I had a plain pointer to the string, so I just passed the `p+1`]

Comment: you mean the entire code? or just the part where I pass the string?

Comment: Just the parts with the string will do.

Comment: You can get some mileage and ideas by taking a look at other toy Lisp interpreters/compilers including [this one](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) and [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours).

Comment: If you simply want to pass everything to the *right* of every open-paren `(` you encounter, a looping combination of [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) would seem to fit the bill.

Comment: You're doing your parsing wrong. Try a more reasonable approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parsing

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using an intermediate representation? So first parse all whole string to a data structure and then execute it? After all Lisps have had traditionally applicative order which means they evaluate the arguments first before calling the function. The data structure could look something along the lines of a struct which has the first part of the string (ie begin or set in your example) and the rest of the string to process in as a second property (head and rest if you want). Also consider that Trees are more easily constructed through recursion than through iteration, the base case here being reaching the ')' character.

If you are interested in Lisp interpreters and compilers you should checkout Lisp in Small Pieces, well worth the price.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought soemthing like this:

```
string str = "( begin  ( set x  2 ) (set y 3 ) )";

func(str);

...

void func(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(s.size() > i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(')
        {
           func(s.substr(i)); 
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

would do the job. [Obviously, you'll perhaps want to do something else in there too!]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, lisp parsing is done by recursively calling a reader and let the reader "consume" as much data as is necessary. If you're doing this on strings, it may be handy to pass the same string around, by reference, and return a tuple of "this is what I read" and "this is where I finished reading".

So something like this (obviously, in actual code, you may want to pass pointers to offset rather than have a pair-structure and needing to deal with memory-management of that, I elided that to make the code more readable):

```
struct readthing {
  Node *data;
  int offset
}

struct readthing *read (char *str, int offset) {
  if (str[offset] == '(')
    return read_delimited(str, offset+1, ')'); /* Read a list, consumer the start */
  ...
}

struct readthing *read_delimited (char *str, int offset, char terminator) {
  Node *list  = NULL;
  offset = skip_to_next_token(str, offset);
  while (str[offset] != terminator) {
    struct readthing *foo = read(str, offset);
    offset = foo->offset;
    list = do_cons(foo->data, list);
  }
  return make_readthing(do_reverse(list), offset+1);
}
```